# Optional dependencies for add_custom_command

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

If I include non-existent files in `DEPENDS` section of `add_custom_command`, it fails. Is there a way to specify the dependency may not exist, but if it's created the command should be rerun?

Specifically, I am using Coco/R, which requires `Parser.frame` and `Scanner.frame` file to exist either in the same directory as the grammar file or one specified by a command line argument, and `Copyright.frame` which can exist or not. So I do this:

```
foreach(FRAME_DIR IN ITEMS ${GRAMMAR_DIR} ${ARG_FRAME_DIR})
    foreach(FRAME_FILE_NAME IN ITEMS Copyright Scanner Parser)
        set(FULL_FRAME_FILE ${FRAME_DIR}/${FRAME_FILE_NAME}.frame)
        if(EXISTS ${FULL_FRAME_FILE})
            list(APPEND FRAME_FILES ${FULL_FRAME_FILE})
        endif()
    endforeach()
endforeach()

...

set(GEN_SOURCES ${ARG_OUTPUT_DIR}/Scanner.h ${ARG_OUTPUT_DIR}/Parser.h ${ARG_OUTPUT_DIR}/Scanner.cpp ${ARG_OUTPUT_DIR}/Parser.cpp)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${GEN_SOURCES}
    COMMAND ${COCOCPP} ${COCOCPP_ARGS}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${ARG_GRAMMAR}
    DEPENDS ${FRAME_FILES}
    VERBATIM)

add_library(${ARG_TARGET} ${GEN_SOURCES})
```

If I comment out `if` inside `foreach`, I get

```
ninja: error: '../verification/debug/config/Copyright.frame', needed by 'verification/gen/config/Parser.h', missing and no known rule to make it
```

at build time. With this `if`, the files are generated but if I create `Copyright.frame` later, of course the build program will not know about it.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of what you're trying to do? I would either design a generator expression that computed the right set of dependencies or attach the same command to the target building the optional file via `POST_BUILD`.

Comment: It would also be good to see the exact failure you're getting / an MRE for producing it.

Comment: I've added what I am actually doing. Of course, that's not an MRE, but I'll do that tomorrow if still needed. It should be enough to use a command which checks for the existence of a file and writes the result to another. Too bad there's no CMake playground (that I could find).

Comment: Can `Copyright.frame` be an empty file? Can't you just check if the file exists at configuration stage? `if I create Copyright.frame later,` then reconfigure your projects, that's anyway usual when you add a file, you are usually expected to reconfigure cmake.

Comment: "Can't you just check if the file exists at configuration stage?" That's what I do at the moment, and ask if there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For common generators, you can use DEPFILE to generate Make-ish dependency just like `gcc -MT -MD` does with include files. You have to write a wrapper that will detect if the file exists or if not, and then generate the file.

The depfile looks generally like this:

```
output: source1 source2
```

And `output` has to be relative to CMAKE_BINARY_DIR (this took me sooooooo long to find out) and `source1` let be absolute. And you have to also escape spaces and tabs and newlines and `#` (!) in names. Generally:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
# Example for one file
set(output ${ARG_OUTPUT_DIR}/Scanner.h)
# Relative to BINARY_DIR!
file(RELATIVE_PATH outputbinrela "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}" "${output}")
set(depfile "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Scanner.h.d" ABSOLUTE)
add_custom_command(
   OUTPUT ${someoutput}
   DEPFILE ${depfile}
   # TODO: write it in cmake, to be portable
   COMMAND sh ./thescript.sh
        "${outputbinrela}" "${depfile}" "${input}"
        ${FRAME_DIR}/Copyright.frame
   DEPENDS ${input}
   WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
   VERBATIM
)
```

```
# ./thescript.sh
outputbinrela="$1"
depfile="$2"
input="$3"
copyright="$4"

# Check if the file exists - if it does, add it to depfile
if [[ -e "$copyright" ]]; then
    copyright=$(readlink -f "$copyright") # absolute!
    echo "$outputbinrela: $copyright" > "$depfile"
else
    echo "$outputbinrela:" > "$depfile"
fi

# Run the command to generate output.
yourcommand "$copyright" > "$input"
```

I once wrote such system for `m4` preprocessor, you can check out [this script](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kcmakelib/-/blob/08dc26cc852ebdeffcfda1b8911797db647f5959/cmake/k/m4_script.cmake#L5) that runs m4 preprocessor and grabs m4 included files and generates depfile, and [this script](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kcmakelib/-/blob/08dc26cc852ebdeffcfda1b8911797db647f5959/cmake/k/m4.cmake#L87) that calls `add_custom_command( ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -Pthe_other_script.cmake DEPFILE ...)`.

Still, if you add `Copyright.frame` file, cmake will *not* pick it up on the first run, but if you modify something else, then depfile will be regenerated and the depdency will be picked. Or you could just re-generate depfile for example on each build.

Comment: "And output has to be relative to CMAKE_BINARY_DIR (this took me sooooooo long to find out)" -- not as of CMake 3.20! See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0116.html#policy:CMP0116